# nor $_POST, $_GET passing my values

Tags: php, html

I have a foreach loop listing the unique codes as links:

```
<a href="#" class="charcoal_link" value="<?php echo $id_to ?>" style="line-height: 20px;" onclick="showMessageArea(this); return false;">
<?php echo $uniqueCode1?>
    <span class="pink_text"><?php echo $uniqueCode2?></span>
<?php echo $uniqueCode3?>
</a>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id_to ?>" />
<form id="message_area" style="display:none" method="post" action="<?php echo ADDRESS; ?>messageSent.php?id=<?php echo $id_to ?>">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input name="message" type="textarea" rows="10" cols="20" value="<?php echo $message ?>" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Send" />
        </td>       
    </tr>
</form>
```

the above is also in another form tag: `<form name = "contacts" method="post">`
the action part works fine but in messageSent.php i do:

```
var_dump($_POST);
var_dump($_GET);
```

and the output gives me:

```
NULL
array(1) { ["id"]=> string(2) "36" }
```

1. Where is "message"?
2. "id" contains the wrong id. It is not the id of the unique code I clicked on.

Comment: it should be `<textarea name="..." id=".."....>VALUE</textarea>`

Comment: <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="20" id="message" value="<?php echo $message ?>"></textarea>

fixed thanks! but it is still not passing my message to messageSent.php??

Comment: [Validate. Validate. Validate.](http://validator.w3.org/) — there is no `value` attribute for the `textarea` element. (Damien did not tell you to add a value attribute, so it isn't fixed).

Comment: ooo ok how will i be able to pass $message on to messageSent.php then please? i am new to html and php ond dont know a whole lot yet

Comment: Do what @Damian said (or look up textarea in the manual).

Comment: i stripped it and took out <table> <tr> and <td> tags
    <form id="message_area" style="display:none" method="post" action="<?php echo ADDRESS; ?>messageSent.php?id=<?php echo $id_to ?>">
    <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="20" id="message"></textarea>
    <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Send" />
    </form>

is this better?

Comment: thanks i managed to pass on the message.. only thing now is it is passing the wrong id thus not the one i clicked on although when i view the page source $id_to contains the correct value for each link but in messageSent it is the wrong one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <a href="#" class="charcoal_link" value="<?php echo $id_to ?>" style="line-height: 20px;" onclick="showMessageArea(this); return false;">
    <?php echo $uniqueCode1?>
        <span class="pink_text"><?php echo $uniqueCode2?></span>
    <?php echo $uniqueCode3?>
    </a>
 <form id="message_area" style="display:none" method="post" action="<?php echo ADDRESS; ?>messageSent.php?id=<?php echo $id_to ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id_to ?>" />

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="20"><?php echo $message ?></textarea>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Send" />
            </td>       
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

You cannot have a form inside a form.. you must do them seperate or else in the same form....

I fixed the HTML markup for you

Comment: thank you very much! i started this job with NO html php OR javascript knowledge and had to jump in and work on code and learn as i go along...no time to do a course.. yikes!

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML is invalid. Among the **many** errors you have made: You can't have a form inside a table but around a tr. The browser is error correcting by moving the form element to somewhere where it is allowed, and leaving the inputs alone (since inputs can be inside td elements).

[Validate. Validate. Validate.](http://validator.w3.org/)

There are so many problems with that fragment of HTML that you have shared, that you would probably benefit from a [beginner's guide to authoring webpages](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/1-introduction-to-the-web-standards-cur/#toc).

Comment: HTML has rules about what elements may be inside what other elements. You are not following those rules. The browser is looking at the not-HTML you are sending it and trying to recover from all your errors. It is not recovering in the way that you want. Use the validator (by clicking the link in my answer) to find all the errors you have made in the HTML, then fix them.

Comment: thanks i have inherited this code from some-one and also new to all this and must learn as i go along :)